# Big gap between Vuetify <v-select> component and its selectable content

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

Why do I have such a big distance between my select box and it's selectable content ?

I'm using Vuetify in VueJS component in Laravel 7.

[image]

```
<template>
  <v-app class="container">
    <v-data-table
      hide-default-header
      hide-default-footer
      :headers="headers"
      :items="items"
      :items-per-page="filter.items_per_page"
      @click:row="getData"
      no-data-text="No data."
      dense
      style="background: transparent"
    >
      <template
        v-slot:footer
        v-if="items.length"
      >
          <v-row no-gutters>
            <v-col cols="2">
              <v-select
                :items=[10,50,100]
                v-model="filter.items_per_page"
                @change="onPageChange(1)"
                label="Rows per page"
                outlined
                dense
              ></v-select>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

=== EDIT ===

Vuetify variables are loaded as below:

`resources/sass/app.scss`

```
@import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
@import '~@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.min.css';
```

Comment: Have you loaded the right css? Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @AneesHameed Thanks for your reply. I have updated my post to show how Vuetify styles are loaded.

Comment: If this is still an issue. I had a similar behavior because I also had bootstrap css loaded on the page just for the navigation. After removing bootstrap css everything was fine again